# Как считать текстовой файл, выгружаемый в форму, из JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html5, файлы, fileupload, big-data

Мне нужно написать веб-приложение, которое обрабатывало бы CSV документы, порядком 20 миллионов строк на документ. Оно бы само по себе ещё ничего, но стандартный объект FileReader имеет только метод считывания всего файла, а мне нужно отобразить процессбар. Кроме того, я переживаю, что программа может просто повиснуть из-за строки такого размера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) с [new FileReader().readAsArrayBuffer()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer). Просто разбить массив на кусочки через "\n".charCodeAt(0) и декодировать с [TextDecoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder/TextDecoder).

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>

        const r_char_code = "\r".charCodeAt(0);

        function detectEncoding(subArr,func){  
            const isUnicode = subArr[subArr.length-1]!=r_char_code;
            const decoder = isUnicode?new TextDecoder():new TextDecoder('windows-1251');

            const str = decoder.decode(subArr);

            console.log({
                result: str,
                encoding: isUnicode?"utf-8":"windows-1251"
            });

            func(str);
        }

        function parseByteArray(arr,func){
            let tmp = [];
            arr.forEach((byte,i)=> {
                const char = String.fromCharCode(byte);

                if(char!='\n'){
                    tmp.push(byte);
                }

                //line by line or EOF
                if(char=='\n'||i==arr.length-1){

                    const buf = Uint8Array.from(tmp);

                    for(let i=0;i!=tmp.length+1;i++){
                        buf[i]=tmp[i];
                    }

                    detectEncoding(buf,func);

                    tmp=[];
                }
            });
        }

        function readFileAsByteArray(file){
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

            reader.onloadend=()=>{

                if(reader.error){
                    throw new Errow(":-(");
                }

                parseByteArray(new Uint8Array(reader.result), console.log);
            }
        }

        function readLineByLine(){
            const input = document.createElement('input');
            input.type = 'file';
            input.accept = '.txt,.csv,.md';
            input.click();

            input.onchange = ()=>{
                readFileAsByteArray(input.files[0]);
            }
        }    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="readLineByLine()">Go!</button>
</body>
```

Проверить можно на [pasteBin](https://jsbin.com/batihav)